# nginx location redirect to folder with name as requested domain

Tags: nginx

I'm new to nginx and I want to do this:

```
If the URL contains "/assets" redirect to "/communities/$url_domain"
```

In other words:

```
Requested: "http://www.cats.com/assets/superfile.png"
Redirected:"http://www.cats.com/communities/cats.com/superfile.png"
```

It's something super simple but it's not working.

**What I have done**

```
location /assets {
    root /communities/$host;
}
```

But whenever I try to access a file from /assets I get a

```
404 Not Found

nginx/1.8.1
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I activated logs and saw this:

```
2016/02/10 17:27:16 [error] 31#0: *1 open() "/communities/www.cats.com/assets/superfile.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.1.254, server: _, request: "GET /assets/superfile.png HTTP/1.1", host: "www.cats.com"
```

I'll investigate more If I can extract the domain part of the url

**EDIT2**:
Directory structure

```
/
--/communities/
--------------/cats.com/
---------------------superfile.png
--------------/dogs.com/
---------------------superfile.png
```

So, for example:

1. Users will request this URL
   **www.cats.com/assets/superfile.png**
2. Users will see the same URL.
3. Nginx internally will look for: 
   **www.cats.com/communities/cats.com/superfile.png**

Comment: What directory are the files in? And what URL are users supposed to see?

Comment: I edited to display the info you requested. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an `alias` instead:

```
location /assets/ {
    alias /communities/$host/;
}
```

Comment: The problem is $host variable which is "www.cats.com". It is possible to get only " cats.com" and remove the subdomain?

Comment: Maybe if you use Lua or something. But you really should just find a better way to organize your files.

Comment: Oh, we can't change the directory structure. Its a map to different domains we have with out partners. I'll take a look at Lua. Thanks!